# Automatically setting UIScrollView content size to scrollview size

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiscrollview

I am using **auto layout (iOS6)**. My Scroll View `ContentSize` is `(768,1200)` (i am using ipad) which i am setting in `ViewDidAppear`. I have another view on that `ViewController`. You can see my view hierarchy below.

The another view is hidden.

The problem is that when i show and hide another view, It sets the `ContentSize` of scroll view to frame size of scrollview.

[image: View Controller Scene]

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your constraints to see if they are "bonded".

If you are using storyboards you can click on the element you want and add or delete constraints.

Try selecting your view then go to `editor > pin > width` (and height) for example.

This should fix it.

Ps: sometimes the Xcode add some unwanted constraints, specially if you move the object, the constraints "reset".